# Using ColorBrewer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, color

I've been using [ColorTool](http://ColorTool) (based on supreme [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/)) for most of my mapping needs in ArcMap. After migrating to ArcGIS 10 I discovered that it will [no longer](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=1592) be a case.

Are there any other options to include ColorBrewer palettes in ArcGIS 10?

Comment: There was recently a blog post by the ESRI mapping center on Color tools in general that may be of interest, http://goo.gl/475oV . Although hopefully celenius's workaround will suffice, I don't doubt one could save a few custom formats to suffice most needs.

Comment: neither of these solutions works.

Comment: There is a working link for the ArcGIS Colorbrewer style in this question:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225890/where-can-i-get-an-archived-copy-of-the-colorbrewer-style-file-for-arcgis-10?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need color scheme of ColorBrewer, http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14403 is a workaround while waiting for new update of ColorTool.

Comment: Excellent - exactly what I needed :]

Comment: The link is not working as at 9/1/2018 and the new branded codesharing.arcgis.com does not have it (as far as my patience allows).

Answer (score 5):

Here is Nice information about it.
http://gis-techniques.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-get-color-brewer-ramp-in-arcmap.html

Answer (score 3):

National Cancer Institute have not updated the excellent ColorTool for ArcGIS to ArcMap 10 yet:suggest that an email request sent to the ColorTool Technical Support: 
gistools@imsweb.com

http://gis.cancer.gov/tools/colortool/

Answer (score 3):

From a [previous](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/are-there-any-convenient-sources-of-color-palettes-to-use-in-arcgis-software-whil/1664#1664) comment I made:
I emailed the developers ([gis.cancer.gov/tools/colortool](http://gis.cancer.gov/tools/colortool/)) and received the response: "The current installer does not fully succeed in ArcMap 10 environments, however you can manually add the "ColorToolPro9_2.0.tlb" from the installation location (usually c:\program files\NCI GIS Tools\colortool) to add the command to a toolbar. " Which I suppose is a satisfactory workaround.

Comment: Hi,  I tried VietTanh Le's approach but I want this toolbar to work to avoid cluttering of color maps.  Did this work for you?  I went to Cutomize->Toolbars and then "add from file" and it says ColorTool9 NC_Toolbar are added but I couldnt find it in either of toolbar list or command list

Comment: This thread is a bit old but I encountered the same result.
"Add from file", window popped up saying toolbar had been loaded but was unable to find it in list of toolbars or commands.

Answer (score 2):

All the links from the previous answers did not work anymore (at least for me) as of Nov 2019. The `ColorBrewer.style` file for ArcGIS 10.xxx can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/ISUEOGTP/GISTaskSheets/blob/master/ColorBrewer.style).

Copy the `.style` file to `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\Styles` (for ArcGIS 10.6). Then add any shapefile to a blank ArcMap document.

- Double click on the layer, go to Symbology tab.
- Choose Features > Single symbol.
- Click on the Symbol box. in the Symbol Selector window, click on Style References.
- Scroll down to find and check the box next to ColorBrewer. Click on Set as Default List too.
- Donezo !

[image: Example showing ColorBrewer palettes in ArcGIS]

Reference: [Importing ColorBrewer Style Ramps into ArcMap](https://store.extension.iastate.edu/product/15575)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not completely wedded to ArcGIS, QGIS has really nice custom color ramp capabilities for both vector and raster.

Useful info:

http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/19/50-single-band-raster-layer-symbology-in-qgis.html

and

http://anitagraser.com/2011/11/02/more-color-ramps-for-qgis/