# Where can I get an archived copy of the ColorBrewer style file for ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, color-ramp, colorbrewer

ColorBrewer palettes are not available in ArcMap. There was [ColorTool](https://gis.cancer.gov/tools/colortool/), a plugin for ArcGIS 9.x developed by National Cancer Institute, but as indicated in [this question from 6 years ago](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6453), it was never upgraded to ArcGIS 10.

Answers to that question elicited the response to download the style file from http://codesharing.arcgis.com/?dbid=14403. However, this domain no longer appears to be maintained, and no style file is available for download.

Does anyone know of another source for this style file?

**Edit:** The nonexistent file is also linked to from http://www.gisuser.org.nz/tips-and-tricks, which conveniently explains, with screenshots, how to import the style file once you have it.

Comment: Or here http://www.reachresourcecentre.info/arcgis-colorbrewer-color-ramp-style

Comment: Blimey @Midavalo I've been looking for that file for ages! +++1! :)

Comment: @Hornbydd I'm wondering if there's a way we can save the file somewhere so we don't lose the link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Reach Resource Center](http://www.reachresourcecentre.info/arcgis-colorbrewer-color-ramp-style) has a archive copy of a Color Brewer ArcMap style file available for download.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem last year trying to get hold of the style file. I contacted Cynthia Brewer directly, got no response...

I then contacted the web developers behind [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) and they pointed me to a defunct ArcGIS 9.3 tool... Obviously not ESRI users!

When I pointed this out they simply removed the link from their site which was pointing to ArcScripts so now they have nothing... After maybe what 6 months nothing has been replaced, shame as their site is quite helpful.

I believe ArcGIS Pro has the many colorbrewer colour schemes.

The link that @Midavalo provides above is the style file squirrelled away on some other website, nice one! Works in ArcGIS 10.5.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.reachresourcecentre.info/arcgis-colorbrewer-color-ramp-style) worked for me in ArcGIS 10.3

Edit: I see now it's the same link @Midavalo posted. Please, put your comment as an answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can download the .style file at this Git repo: https://github.com/ISUEOGTP/GISTaskSheet mentioned in these PDF instructions: https://indicator.extension.iastate.edu/projects/tasksheets/reports/PM2082-14e.pdf

These instructions also explain how to import it once you have it.

Comment: Link to the PDF instructions have changed. You can now get the most recent PDF at https://store.extension.iastate.edu/product/Importing-ColorBrewer-Style-Ramps-into-ArcMap

Answer (score 1):

new link for the .style file: https://github.com/ISUEOGTP/GISTaskSheets

Comment: As of 11/2022, this is the correct link to the ColorBrewer .style file. (It's in the 'Classes' subfolder.) I successfully imported its color ramps into ArcMap 10.8 using the instructions in the iastate.edu PDF others have linked.