# Colour gradation in ArcMap - shades of blue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, color, colormap

I have created a map of the United States with concentric circles around a geographic point, namely Detroit. I was able to give the different circles around the city colours of different grey shading. To do so, I used ArcMap's colours grey10-grey80. This is the result:
[image]

I have tried to reproduce the same map with a different colour shading. Ideally, I would like to have colour gradiation of different **blue** shades. The problem is that there exist too few and only very irregular predefined blue tones. I tried creating equal shades with ArcMap's colour selector but the result were **irregular** colours too. In the resulting map below, for example, some differences between the colours are **barely visible**, others are too large.
[image]

Because of that, I would like to ask if there exist any predefined shades of blue tones that give a clear (and aesthetically pleasing) result where differences are consistent and clearly visible like in the first (grey) map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a site like [colour brewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=Blues&n=8) the get the RGB or HEX values for a sensible sequence of blue colours.
I've set the link above to already show you a sequence of 8 blue colours.

You can then manually add these into ArcMap and save them as a default style.  The style will then be available in all future map documents.

If you don't know how to add the colours and save them as a style, leave a comment & I'll edit this answer to also walk you through the process.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for such a simple solution to my problem. The colour brewer you linked comes in very handy for me.

Comment: To compliment Dan's answer [here is a thread linking to a ArcMap style file](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225890/where-can-i-get-an-archived-copy-of-the-colorbrewer-style-file-for-arcgis-10) which has the colorbewer styles, so no need to copy RGB values, just add it to your ArcMap and use.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any existing blue color ramp and modify the range as you like as you can see below:

[image]

Right-click on the `Color ramp -> Go to Properties`:

[image]

You can change the blue range of the two colors as you can see below:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This looks good. For now I go with Dan_h_b's answer (hence accepted) because it is a bit faster and I currently don't have much time but I will keep your answer in mind for the future.